# How to convince the investors without actually revealing the idea in the first place?

Tags: investing, start-up

Let's say I've developed an application and it's all done; nevertheless, it still needs supporting resources and a good marketing and all the other matters that are required for a success; but, I don't afford them for ages!

So, the Angle-Investors or the Venture-Capital firms would certainly ask about the app or require briefing. I suspect if they grasp the idea, they will very simply neglect me and start their own! The app took me, almost six months to create (I'm a skilled professional but still a single individual); but for the wealthy entities, after grasping the idea, it would be a matter of a few weeks to produce a way better alternative with world-class support and marketing and all the resources, to completely ruin what I've worked so hard on, in a blink!

So, my question is: how may I convince them for their support without initially revealing the main logic behind the app, to get a rigid contract first, and then share the confidential with them? (I'm simply looking for safety)

(Please don't suggest going to friends and family, as it's a no brainier and it's not what I mean to learn!)

Comment: During the South Sea Bubble in 1720, investors (apocryphally) put their money into what was described as “An undertaking of great advantage, but nobody to know what it is”. So it can be done, with sufficiently gullible investors.

Comment: @MikeScott Thank you for your reply, Mike, I appreciate it; Even if "gullibility" was an option, I would instantly refused it, since it will ruin the work just in another aspect! (let alone the Venture-Capital firms or the angel-investors, they are real wolves), In a nutshell, I'm looking for safety and not to fool anyone.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about personal finance.

Comment: True; it's really about business and business law.

Comment: Make them sign an NDA?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's really an Intellectual Property Law and/or Contract Law question, not personal finance even if the company is a sole proprietorship... and free amateur legal advice on the Internet is usually not worth what you paid for it.

Answer (score 8):

If an established company could replicate your solution and put you out of business in a matter of weeks, you unfortunately don't have a particularly viable business.  Or at least not one that venture capitalists are likely to want to invest in.  A venture capitalist is going to be looking for some sort of barrier to entry or some other defensible advantage your company would have.  There would be little to gain from investing in a startup whose only product could be cloned by bigger companies a week or two after it was advertised.

Venture capitalists are not in the business of stealing ideas-- that would cost them far more in reputation than they'd gain by ripping you off.  In theory, you could ask them to sign a non-disclosure agreement.  But most venture capitalists have far more people trying to pitch them on ideas than they have time to listen so they're probably not going to sign your agreement.  Particularly when lots of people tend to have roughly the same idea at roughly the same time so there is a decent probability that someone else would pitch them a vaguely similar idea.

It doesn't hurt to have documentation of your ideas.  Things like a source control repository with dates for commits will show when you developed particular features for example.

Answer (score 5):

You need to protect your Intellectual Property (IP). This could be through patents (technical or design patents), copyright mechanisms, non-disclosure agreements, etc. In fact, the strength of the protected IP is a huge factor for the viability of a business and hence it's something that all investor look at VERY closely.

You will need to do this anyway: as soon as you launch your app (alone or with help) it's public knowledge and everyone can copy any aspect of the app that's not specifically protected.

Your best bet is to grab a few hours from an IP professional and have them look at your stuff.